# Como mapear resposta de request REST

Tags: java, spring, rest

Estou consumindo uma API REST com `RestTemplate` e ela não segue as boas práticas, como usar os códigos de status HTTP, por exemplo.

### Resposta no caso de sucesso:

```
{
    "435": {
        "Codigo": "435",
        "Tipo": "",
        "Corretor": "62",
        "Cliente": "48304",
        "DataHora": "2016-04-27 14:18:24",
        "DataHoraAtualizacao": "",
        "Assunto": "Visita - Imóvel 2",
        "Local": "",
        "Texto": "",
        "DataHoraInicio": "2016-04-28 12:00:00",
        "DataHoraFinal": "2016-04-28 12:20:00",
        "Particular": "Nao",
        "Imovel": "2",
        "DiaInteiro": "Nao",
        "Tarefa": "Nao",
        "Concluido": "Nao"
    },
    "687": {
        "Codigo": "687",
        "Tipo": "",
        "Corretor": "20",
        "Cliente": "33040",
        "DataHora": "2016-07-18 17:09:28",
        "DataHoraAtualizacao": "",
        "Assunto": "Visita - Imóvel 2",
        "Local": "",
        "Texto": "teste",
        "DataHoraInicio": "2016-07-28 08:00:00",
        "DataHoraFinal": "2016-07-28 09:00:00",
        "Particular": "Nao",
        "Imovel": "2",
        "DiaInteiro": "Nao",
        "Tarefa": "Nao",
        "Concluido": "Nao"
    }}
```

Até aqui é possível perceber uma estrutura de Mapa, conforme segue:

```
Map<String, MeuObjeto> meusObjetos;
```

#### Classe `MeuObjeto`

```
public class MeuObjeto {

    @JsonProperty("Codigo")
    private Integer codigo;

    @JsonProperty("Tipo")
    private String tipo;

    @JsonProperty("Corretor")
    private String corretor;

    @JsonProperty("Cliente")
    private String cliente;

    @JsonProperty("DataHora")
    private String dataHora;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraAtualizacao")
    private String dataHoraAtualizacao;

    @JsonProperty("Assunto")
    private String assunto;

    @JsonProperty("Local")
    private String local;

    @JsonProperty("Texto")
    private String texto;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraInicio")
    private String dataHoraInicio;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraFinal")
    private String dataHoraFinal;

}
```

### Resposta no caso de erro (sem registros):

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "A pesquisa não retornou resultados."
}
```

Como mapeio a classe para prever os dois casos?

Comment: Você pode criar uma segmentação de funções referente a instância da classe para gerar saídas de eventos com base na resposta.

Comment: Não é retornado o _status code_ no cabeçalho de resposta? Ou é sempre retorno algo como _200_ e o _status code_ "correto" está sempre no _payload_?

Comment: A API do fornecedor é exatamente desse jeito, e não utiliza os status http.

Comment: Nesse caso acho que você  vai precisar criar uma classe com os atributos `status` e `message` e quando receber a resposta testar se o Map é nulo, se for, é porque a resposta deve ser de erro.

Comment: Ok, mas onde estará o map na classe?

Comment: ja pensou numa lista de map? ex: ` List<Map<String, Object>>  ou depende do seu caso, Map<String, List<Object>> `

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia colocar o tratamento para resposta de erro se houver uma exception ao fazer a serialização da resposta.

```
 try {
    MeuObjeto mo = new MeuObjeto(...)//recebe o response do request
 } catch (Exception e) {
    ErroMsg em = new ErroMsg(...)
 }
```